# Getting event from a table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

Im beginning my ios development and for beginning i thought it will be fun to make a measure converter.

I managed to create with storyboards the table view with segues, custom cells with textfields and labels corresponding to different dimensions but now im stuck and cant find an answer in tutorials or book i was reading.

In each cell there is a textfield corresponding to given dimension (ie. meters, centimeters etc.). How to get an event that textfield in given row is finished editing, and change other textfields after calculations? (cells are created from an array containing dimensions names and values necessary for calculations)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UILabel *label;
    UITextField *field;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DimensionCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    field = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    field.delegate = self;
    NSString *DimensionLabel = [self.dimension objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.text = DimensionLabel;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Since you will need to change all of the textfields whenever any of them change, it would probably be easiest to just create outlets for them all and refer to them directly whenever a textfield is done editing (or has changed if you prefer it to happen in real time).

Comment: @Inafziger thats why i dont want to use outlets. I want textfields to be created automatically, so i can just add a new dimension to an array and it will ready to go. Also it will help me to use the same view for different measures

Comment: In that case, it may be easiest to just update your data source and call reloadData on the table view, since you need to update them all anyway.  The other option is to loop through all of the table views visibleCells and get the references to the labels just like you do in cellForRowAtIndexPath in your original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set delegate of UITextField as the viewController presenting the tableView.

You can give each textField tag or you can check for the point of the textField in `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate to find the indexPath for identifying textField.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.customTextField.delegate = self;
    //You can use tag if there is only one section
    //If there is more than one section then this will be ambiguos
    cell.customTextField.tag = indexPath.row;

    //Set other values

    return cell;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    CGPoint textFieldOrigin = [textField convertPoint:textField.frame.origin toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:textFieldOrigin];
    //Now you can use indexPath for updating your dataSource 

}
```

Comment: thanks! first part works good - i can get to the textfield. But now how to get all other textfields in other cells?

Comment: @mjanisz1 This is generic. You need to set delegate to all the textFields in the cells. They all will go through that `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method. You need to introduce your specific way to use the indexPath to find out which is which. Or if you can share more info about the dataSource and cell. I can give you suggestion.

Comment: I edited the question so you can see how i make the cell. I tried to change the textfield.text to just a simple string, but it changes only in the one that is finished editing (sry i have no idea how to connect it to all textfields available). If you explain me this the rest will be just trivial ;)

Comment: @mjanisz1 That is all needed. If you giving tag, make it unique. Can you little more specific. Your current set up looks fine. The didEndEditing method is only called when a textField resigns being firstResponder.

Comment: thx! i thought about giving unique tags, but found it a bit "unelegant". All the time i expected there is a more sophisticated method to edit each of the same ui elements in every cell on event :)

Comment: @mjanisz1 Using `tag` is common way of identify UI elements, there is no loss of elegance in it. When you are changing the data of cell, the usual practice is to edit the dataSource and then reloading the whole cell to reflect the changes. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `restorationId` property of UITextField. Give restorationID of each textfield like this :

```
textField.restorationID = @"dimension1";
textField.delegate = self;
```

Then in following textfield delegate method you can check for restorationID to identify which textField was edited.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if([textField.restorationID isEqualToString:@"dimension1"])
    {
         // perform calculation and any updation required.
    }
}
```

I just suggest that you use your dimension name as restorationID. This may help you identify the textfield in delegate method.